# Why "we can use the compactness of the Brillouin zone to contract the sphere back onto itself on the other side"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-field-theory

This is from David Tong's Gauge Theory Notes Sec 4.3.3 page 224(book) or page 26(pdf)

http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/4lattice.pdf

Consider Hamiltonian $H=v_i(\vec{k})\sigma_i+\epsilon(\vec{k})Id_2$ where $\sigma_i$ are pauli matrices and $k$ takes value in Brillouin zone. Assume $H$'s Hessian non-singular at $k=k_\alpha$ where $k_\alpha$ is the point with 2 bands touching.

"By the time we get to a sphere $S^2_{biggest}$ which encompasses all the points, we
can use the compactness of the Brillouin zone to contract the sphere back onto itself
on the other side. The winding around this sphere must, therefore, vanish."

1. Why there are only finitely many such $k_\alpha$ with 2 bands touching? It is clear that Brillouin zone is compact. Is analyticity of $v_i(k)$ used here to assume $H$ is non-trivial Hamiltonian?
2. Why the compactness of the Brillouin zone implies contracting the biggest sphere back onto itself on the other side? Is this saying this contraction induces a winding identified as $-1\in\pi_2(S^2)$? Why does the biggest sphere including all $k_\alpha$ contract onto itself on the other side? I could guess if that is the case with non-trivial element of $\pi_2(S^2)$, I would get a contradiction by homotopy argument.